# Datagrip - PostgreSQL connection to Heroku not showing tables

Tags: postgresql, datatables, heroku-postgres, datagrip

I connected to my Heroku PostgreSQL database with Jetbrains Datagrip. Authentication was successful, I didn't need to specify advantage properties when connecting, when I filled *host, db, username and password*, **Test connection** was successful.

When I write query to console, everything works, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM users
```

find all users in my database.

I have problem, when I want to see **tables** in my database structure. They don't appear. In project tree, I can see only **Database_name -> schemas -> public -> key_id_seq** (image: [Project tree structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgDCl.jpg)). When I click on synchronize button, I get an error:

```
[42703] org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column t.relhasoids does not exist
  Position: .
Error encountered when performing Introspect database *db_name* schema public (details): ERROR: column t.relhasoids does not exist
  Position: .
ERROR: column t.relhasoids does not exist
  Position:
```

Am I doing something wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datagrip updated to version **DataGrip 2019.3.3, Build #DB-193.6494.42, built on February 12, 2020**, Now working :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using "Introspect using JDBC metadata". This fixed it for me when (I think) I had a  version mismatch between postgresql server and DataGrip client.

Under your connection settings -> Options tab -> check Introspect using JDBC metadata

According to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/data-sources-and-drivers-dialog.html#optionsTab :

> Switch to the JDBC-based introspector.
>
> To retrieve information about database objects (DB metadata), DataGrip
> uses the following introspectors:
>
> 1. A native introspector (might be unavailable for certain DBMS). The
>    native introspector uses DBMS-specific tables and views as a source of
>    metadata. It can retrieve DBMS-specific details and produce a more
>    precise picture of database objects.
> 2. A JDBC-based introspector (available for all the DBMS). The JDBC-based
>    introspector uses the metadata provided by the JDBC driver. It can
>    retrieve only standard information about database objects and their
>    properties.
>
> Consider using the JDBC-based intorspector when the native
> introspector fails or is not available.
>
> The native introspector can fail, when your database server version is
> older than the minimum version supported by DataGrip.
>
> You can try to switch to the JDBC-based introspector to fix problems
> with retrieving the database structure information from your database.
> For example, when the schemas that exist in your database or database
> objects below the schema level are not shown in the Database tool
> window.

Answer (score 0):

My case was different here. But I was getting the similar error:

An error has occurred:

```
01:15:21 PM: Error: ERROR:  column rel.relhasoids does not exist
LINE 1: ...t_userbyid(rel.relowner) AS relowner, rel.relacl, rel.relhas...
```

I was using **pgadmin 3** to connect to Heroku hosted Postgresql. Then I configure pgadmin 4. The error didn't show on it. For installing pgadmin 4, I used docker approach.

```
docker pull dpage/pgadmin4
docker run -p 5050:80 -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=XXXX@Xmail.com" -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=thirumal" -d dpage/pgadmin4
```

Now, open the browser and navigate **http://localhost:5050/**.